# How can I prove that $2ab \leq a^2 + b^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck with it:
$2ab \leq a^2 + b^2$. Have no idea how to go beyond this ($a,b \geq 0$).

Thanks!

Comment: Try expanding $(a-b)^2$.

Comment: You should remark also that the fact that $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative is useless.

Comment: if $a,b$ are natural numbers , you can do it by mathematical induction

Comment: note that: $$a^2+b^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2 +2ab$$

Answer (score 5):

for any $a,b\in R$ we have that $(a-b)^2\geq 0$ expanding we get
$$a^2-2ab+b^2\geq 0$$
$$a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$$
is then implied

Comment: Could you please point me some reference where I could read more about the "expanding" part?

I actually understood after the second line, but not from where $(a-b)^2$ came. Thanks!

Comment: the expansion is simply $(a-b)^2=(a-b)(a-b)=(a-b)a-(a-b)b=a^2-ba-ab+b^2$ $=a^2-2ab+b^2$

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I was just wondering where I could find more to read about the proof by expansion (or any other example where it is applied)! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is any such things, it is considered a fairly elementary thing to do. In sweden we ahve a name for it but I can't find it in english.

Comment: On second thought, here http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Algebra/SimpExp/CS.htm http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/factors-expansion-d_1249.html

Comment: @user206695 There is no proof by expansion. I am guessing Zelos Malum saw the initial inequality, moved 2ab to the other said and then recognized the expansion of $(a-b)^2$. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Thank you guys! Now it is more clear! :)

Comment: Welcome! :) It is a pleasure helping people

Answer (score 3):

Start with $2ab \leq a^2 + b^2$.

Note that:

> $2ab \leq a^2 + b^2$
>
> if and only if
>
> $0 \leq a^2 - 2ab + b^2$

Recognize that the RHS is an expansion of something namely

$(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$

Hence,

> $0 \leq a^2 - 2ab + b^2$
>
> if and only if
>
> $0 \leq (a-b)^2$

Now, $0 \leq (a-b)^2$ is true $\forall \ a, b \in \mathbb{R}$